# do while loop with multiple conditions in JAVA

Tags: java

The program keeps track of the product and quantity of the product in a do while loop and can only end if the user inputs the string "ZZZZ" and the integer 0. 
For example, inputting ZZZZ and 5 would not end the loop. But somehow it's still ending.

```
 while (!itemcode.equals("ZZZZ") && (quantity != 0));
```

The output that I'm getting is

```
Please enter the product code and quantity: ZZZZ 5

A105: 0    Price = 0.0
A207: 0    Price = 0.0
D671: 0    Price = 0.0
X111: 0    Price = 0.0
X902: 0    Price = 0.0
Total Price: $0.0
```

Which ends the loop but shouldn't.

Comment: Edit your question to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help if we can't examine how you set `itemcode` **and** `quantity`, but computers do **exactly** what you tell them to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want is this:

```
while (!(itemcode.equals("ZZZZ") && quantity == 0));
```